# Mootools JSON (Pulling top level items)

Tags: javascript, json, mootools

Trying to pull all "titles" from my json request, with no success.

**Current Fiddle** = http://jsfiddle.net/DZkZV/

Current Json:

```
    {
      "title": "Title 1"
    },
    {
      "title": "Title 2"
    },
    {
      "title": "Title 3"
    },
    {
      "title": "Title 4"
    }
```

Current Javascript:

```
var addTopTopItemsLi = function(title){
  title.each(function(){
    var el = new Element('li'),
             htmltxt = new Element('span', {'class': 'pgTitle','html': title.title}).inject(name);
             inject(gallery);
  });

};
```

Comment: Doesn't json have to be contained in single root element? What is written under "Current JSON" is an expression that evaluates to last object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are jumping the gun a little bit now, aren't you :)

http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/DZkZV/1/

points: 
- json needed to be an array of items.
- you have to pass on the whole response and then loop it.
- exceptions in the .each loop and inconsistent references.

p.s. the new firebug 1.8.3 is so poor it failed to show the inner exceptions after the ajax, so frustrating...

Comment: I had a feeling that the "[]" were the problem in this situation, thanks again Dimitar!